# GLSL - Bad performance when changing color in fragment shader in an if-clause

Tags: android, android-ndk

Why does the performance gets bad, when I set the color in an if-clause?
This is my current fragment-shader-code:

```
if(u_habitatSettings.z>0.0)
{
    if(tNames.r<=BLINK && tNames.g<=BLINK && tNames.b<=BLINK && tNames.a>0.0)
    {
        if(v_blinkIndices==BLINK_BE_ASSAULTED)
        {
            tNames=vec4(1, 0, 0, u_habitatSettings.z);
        }
        else if(v_blinkIndices==BLINK_ASSAULT)
        {
            tNames=vec4(0, 0, 1, u_habitatSettings.z);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I have approximately 20 fps. When I comment out the two lines `tNames=vec4(1, 0, 0, u_habitatSettings.z);` and `tNames=vec4(0, 0, 1, u_habitatSettings.z);`, the fps increases to 60fps (max. fps on the device).

Does the problem is because of the if-clauses and the compiler removes them, when commenting out the two lines? Or are the two lines the problem?